# Use Record As Function Argument in RETURNING Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, plpgsql, sql-function

I have a plpgsql function that takes a record as an argument.

I would like to call this function in the `RETURNING` statement of an insert, but am unsure what to put as the argument (`*` does not work) i.e.,

```
-- Postgres 12

INSERT INTO some_table (a, b, c)
VALUES .....
RETURNING
function_that_takes_record_argument(<the_new_record>)
```

What can I use in place of `<the_new_record>`?

Comment: Try `... function_that_takes_record_argument(some_table.*)` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=950e566f02244f90ca88dc2b872cb556

Comment: yes, that works, thank you! Do you know why it needs the table name to work?

Comment: As I understand it is because the `*` expands into fields (several values) while `t.*` or simply `t` means row/record (single value). It is same as for example `select to_json(*) from t` (does not works) and `select to_json(t.*), to_json(t) from t` (works)

Comment: okay, cool. As is tradition, if you want to post an answer I will be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a record/row to a function you need to explicitly specify the record type:

```
create table t(a int, b text);

create or replace function f(r record) returns int language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return r.a;
end $$;

insert into t values(2, 'b');

select f(t.*), f(t), f((a,b)::t) from t;

 f | f | f 
---+---+---
 2 | 2 | 2

insert into t values(3, 'c') returning f(t);

 f 
---
 3
```

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure why your example does not work, but I would try a data-modifying CTE:

```sql
WITH insert_result AS (
    INSERT INTO ... RETURNING * 
)
SELECT your_function_here(insert_result.*)
```

See more at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING